# Cumulative sum based on Subject ID in R

Tags: r

Assume we have dataframe `df`, it looks like this:

| subjectid | event | football_year_baseline | football_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | baseline | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | followup | `NA` | ?? |
| 2 | baseline | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | followup | `NA` | ?? |
| 3 | baseline | 2 | 4 |

I'm trying to fill out the `football_total` column, for purposes of this example, let's assume that the formula is `football_year_baseline` * 2 in the baseline rows.

For the follow-up rows, the result needs to be cumulative based, meaning that the formula is `football_total` from baseline + 2. `subjectid` and `event` should be used to determine which baseline value to add 2 to.

Please note: not all subjects have a follow-up row.

So, `football_row` in row 2 would be 8 -> 6 + 2.

Comment: Is there always only one single follow up, or multiple?

Comment: Maximum of one single follow up row for each subject id. There is either one follow-up for each or no follow up row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention there is at most one single follow up for each study id, an alternative `dplyr` solution using `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  mutate(football_total = case_when(
    event == "baseline" ~ football_total,
    event == "followup" ~ (lag(football_total) + 2)
  ), .by = subjectid)
```

Output:

```
  subjectid    event football_year_baseline football_total
1         1 baseline                      3              6
2         1 followup                     NA              8
3         2 baseline                      0              0
4         2 followup                     NA              2
5         3 baseline                      2              4
```

Data

```
x <- read.table(text = "subjectid   event   football_year_baseline  football_total
1   baseline    3   6
1   followup    NA  NA
2   baseline    0   0
2   followup    NA  NA
3   baseline    2   4", h = TRUE)
```

##### Extended example

To do this across multiple columns, assuming the same nomenclature convention (i.e., "xxx_total"), you can use dplyr's `across()` and  `contains()`. Below  I added two columns, `vball_baseline` and `vball_total`:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("total"), ~ case_when(
    event == "baseline" ~ .x,
    event == "followup" ~ (lag(.x) + 2)
  )), .by = subjectid)
```

Extended Output

```
  subjectid    event football_year_baseline football_total vball_baseline vball_total
1         1 baseline                      3              6              1           2
2         1 followup                     NA              8             NA           4
3         2 baseline                      0              0              3           4
4         2 followup                     NA              2             NA           6
5         3 baseline                      2              4              5           6
```

Extended Data:

```
x <- read.table(text = "subjectid   event   football_year_baseline  football_total vball_baseline vball_total
1   baseline    3   6 1 2
1   followup    NA  NA NA NA
2   baseline    0   0 3 4
2   followup    NA  NA NA NA
3   baseline    2   4 5 6", h = TRUE)
```

Comment: how could this be done if we had several other columns such as tennis, bball, vball etc, all at once? I tried a for loop but keep getting errors

Comment: @fnaber - sure, see if the extended example in the edit helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for 1 or more rows of follow-up. It assumes the `"baseline"` is already the first row in each subject - if not, `arrange()` the data first.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(
    fball_total = case_when(event == "baseline" ~ football_year_baseline * 2, TRUE ~ NA_integer_),
    fball_total = coalesce(fball_total, fball_total[1] + 2 * (row_number() - 1)),
    .by = subjectid
  )
#   subjectid    event football_year_baseline football_total fball_total
# 1         1 baseline                      3              6           6
# 2         1 followup                     NA             NA           8
# 3         2 baseline                      0              0           0
# 4         2 followup                     NA             NA           2
# 5         3 baseline                      2              4           4
```